# execute slideDown with if esle

Tags: javascript, forms, slidedown

I have a form consisting of 2 parts, both on the same page.

I want a `<p>` element to be part two of the form. The `<p>` needs to be invisible and only shown when the first part of the form has been filled in. So when you fill in the form and click next, the `<p>` slides down and shows the rest of the form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").slideUp();
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").slideDown();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please post your HTML too. It's somewhat unclear from your question exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: so whats your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info you have provided i think you are looking for this :-

HTML:-

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Prev">
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Next">
<div>welcome to mypage
    fill all the fields :- Form 1</div>
<p style="display:none">
    Now Fill this section :- Form 2
</p>
```

JS:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").slideUp();
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").slideDown();
  });
});
```

[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zy5xc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

put both part in two div with id's and set style display none for second div.

```
style="display:none"
```

and then use this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("div2").show();
    $("div1").hide().slideUp();
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("div1").show();
    $("div2").hide().slideDown();
  });
});
```